# Music/Sounds sound different after a night out

Tags: hearing, ear, hangover-hungover, soundwaves, sound-amplification-psap

I'm wondering what's causing the following issue:

After a night out to the club (where music is loud) and getting drunk with friends it seems the next day when I wake up that sounds that I know (for example my favorite song) sound different. It's just some notes of the song though.

Any explanation?
Couldn't find any.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Loud music = damaged eardrum?